# How to correctly terminate a thread running an opcua server with open62541 so the server shuts down and can be cleaned up properly

Tags: c, multithreading, signals, opc-ua, open62541

I have an application in C that takes care of polling data form a OPCUA server and broadcasting them to Kafka. in addition to that some datapoints need to be made available to another OPCUA client. For this purpose the application also hosts a barebone OPCUA server itself.

To avoid having to handle client, kafka AND the server on the main thread I am running the server in a pthread. The server itself is taken from the open62541 library.

```
void* startServer(void *vargp)
{
    UA_StatusCode retval = UA_Server_runUntilInterrupt(server);

    return NULL;
}

static void runServer()
{
    int res = setupServer(serverParameters, serverInfos, serverInfosLength);

    ...

    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, startServer, NULL);
}
```

The problem is, that all interrupt signals only reach the main thread. The opcua client and kafka producer are correctly stopped and cleanued up. How would I best go about to correctly top the opcua server that is running in the thread? It should react to SIGINT and SIGTERM just like the client does (which works just fine).

I tried ending the thread by sending it the signal.

```
pthread_kill(thread_id, SIGTERM);
```

But when I clean it up it apparently is still running, which is indicated by an error message saying the server can only be deleted after it has stopped.

I don't have a lot of experience when it comes to server/client architecture and would not only be happy about solutions regarding this specific problem but will also gladly take any suggestions as to how to tackle the handling of the server part in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the Signal handler and use UA_Server_run_iterate until the running variable is set to false.

```
UA_Boolean running = true;
static void stopHandler(int sign) {
    UA_LOG_INFO(UA_Log_Stdout, UA_LOGCATEGORY_SERVER, "received ctrl-c");
    running = false;
}

void* startServer(void *vargp)
{
    UA_Boolean waitInternal = true;
    while(running) {
        UA_Server_run_iterate(server, waitInternal);
    }

    return NULL;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    signal(SIGINT, stopHandler);
    signal(SIGTERM, stopHandler);
    
    ....
 }
```